# Why the following implies that $G \cong H$?

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism, exact-sequence

If I have the following sequence:

$$J \xrightarrow{v} H \xrightarrow{u} G \rightarrow 0 \qquad (1)$$

Where $v$ is the zero map.

Does that mean $G \cong H$ i.e., $G$ isomorphic to $H$?if so why?

Or, do I need the extra assumption that $(1)$ is an exact sequence for $G$ to be isomorphic to $H$? If so, what is also the justification for the isomorphism between $G$ and $H$?

For me, it is clear that $u$ is onto.

Any elaboration will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If it is an *exact sequence,* yes. Just a sequence? No.

Comment: you need exactness. Do you know what is the condition for exactness in degree $H$?

Comment: Yeah I know that the condition for exactness is $\operatorname {ker} u = \operatorname {Im} v $ @JackozeeHakkiuz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the sequence is exact, we have $\operatorname{im}(v) = \ker(u)$. But $\operatorname{im}(u) = G $ since it coincides with the kernel of the zero map, therefore $u$ is surjective. Since you mentioned that $v$ is the zero map, it follows that $u$ is injective. Hence $u$ is an isomorphism between $H$ and $G$. If the sequence is not exact then you can easily find a counterexample to show that it does not imply $G$ and $H$ are isomorphic.

Comment: @Happy A map is injective if and only if it has trivial kernel. If $v$ is the zero map, then $\operatorname{im}(v)$ is trivial and hence so is $\ker(u)$.

Comment: Sorry I deleted my question because I found me understanding why. But then when I refreshed my page I found your answer. ... thank you!